# Importing multiple HTML Pages into a single div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to import multiple HTML External pages into a single div.
Example: I am page1.HTML, page2.html and so on. I have this piece of JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.main').load('page1.html');
});
</script>
```

This works fine except I am not sure how to add multiple pages to become imported into the same div on page load.

Thank my friends.

Comment: Use JQuery.get() - then use the response strings you get back to keep adding to the div.

Comment: Why not use one div per page? Or iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiples then you cant use load. Use `$.get` instead and specify the callback to add them to the div:

```
var pages = ['page1.html', 'page2.html', etc..],
    $main = $('.main'),
    doLoad = function () {
        if(pages.length > 0) {
          // use shift to get the next page off the array
          $.get(pages.shift(), function(content) {
              // append content to .main
              $main.append(content);
              // call do load to get the next entry
              doLoad();
          });
        }
    };

doLoad();
```

Comment: Note that the pages will be added as soon as they load, which is not necessarily the order in the pages array.

Comment: @cristophe: no they wont. This is specifically written to load the pages in the order of the array. The next page is loaded only after the previous page completes since `doLoad` is called from the success callback of the ajax request and the array is processed like a queue.

Comment: oh right, sorry I read this too quickly. So it'll just be slow as pages are loaded one at a time.

Comment: I should also note that this could be done with deferreds but this is much easier to understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var pages=["page1.html","page2.html","page3.html"],
    mainDiv=$(".main");
$.each(pages, function(i,page){
    var newDiv=mainDiv.append("div");
    newDiv.load(page);
});
```

load() will be easier than get() if you only want to load page fragments (which is usually the case if you deal with complete pages that include head tags).

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of HTML-files to load, and iterate through the array with an ajax call for each page, and then use jQuery prepend() to put the contents into your element.